# VBA: Insert ascending Date in Table

Tags: sql, forms, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to simplify the input by users with a code. It's difficult to explain the process so I show you what I mean.

The user only has to Input the following values:

**Event**: `event1`   **From**: 01.01.2017   **To**: `01.04.2017`   **Cost**: `5000`

Result in the Table:

```
event1   01.01.2017   5000
event1   01.02.2017   5000
event1   01.03.2017   5000
event1   01.04.2017   5000
```

I tried it with this code:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim Period As Date

    For Period = "' & Me!FromDate & '" To "' & Me!ToDate & '"

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblEvents (EventName, Date, Costs) VALUES ('" & Me!EventName& "' , '" & Date & "', '" & Me!Costs& "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    Next Date

End Sub
```

Comment: Please tag the proper RDBMS. MS Access ?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771861/insert-sql-command-with-datetime-in-ms-access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following *date calculation* functions:

1. `DateDiff()` to calculate the number of months between your 2 dates
2. `DateAdd()` to create a date by adding a number of months to another date

---

*Edit: Adding infor for the data input*

add 2 textboxes to your form, name them `TextDtFrom` and `TextDtTo`, and give them the format **shortdate** so you'll see a calendar appear to pick up the dates easily.

---

Add a button with this click event :

```vb
Private Sub TheButton_Click()


    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dtFrom As Date
    Dim dtTo As Date
    Dim dtCurrent As Date
    Dim intMonths As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'dtFrom = DateSerial(2017, 1, 1)
    'dtTo = DateSerial(2017, 4, 1)

    dtFrom = TextDtFrom.Value
    dtTo = TextDtTo.Value

    ' Calculate the number of months between the 2 dates
    intMonths = DateDiff("m", dtFrom, dtTo)

    ' Looping on the number of months
    For i = 0 To intMonths

        ' Computing Datefrom + month
        dtCurrent = DateAdd("m", i, dtFrom)

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblEvents (EventName, Date, Costs) VALUES ('" & Me!EventName & "' , '" & Format(dtCurrent, "DD.MM.YYYY") & "', '" & Me!Costs & "')"

        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to find a solution where it is possible to define DateFrom/DateTo with Text- or Comboboxes. Do you know a possible solution for that?

Comment: Yes but you should first tell us more about the technology used. VBA is not enough. Is it MS ACcess or another Office product ??

Comment: Sorry it's MS Access. I think i need a way to connect two Comboboxes to the For Loop.                                                       For Date = "' & Combobox1 & '" To "' & Combobox2 & '"     ... Next Date

Comment: It will not work as expected unless you format the string expressions for the date values correctly: `"' , #" & Format(dtCurrent, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, '"`.

Comment: @Gustav : You are a bit too much sure of something unknown here. It really depends if its date column type  is declared as string or date. I have assumed it is string and it looks like I was correct.

Comment: Then you should have stated that. The data type for dates should always be _DateTime_.