# How to properly save Date into Microsoft Access?

Tags: excel, vba, database, date, ms-access

I am trying to populate my Access Table that has a date column from my excel, so in my excel I have `DateOfBirth` formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`. In my Visual Basic Code this line print my date properly:
`MsgBox "DOB: " & Format(xlWs.Cells(i, 9), "dd/mm/yyyy")`. My problem now is using this code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Persons(PersonName, Dob) VALUES('" & xlWs.Cells(i, 8) & "'," & Format(xlWs.Cells(i, 9), "dd/mm/yyyy") & ");"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

where `xlWs.Cells(i, 9)` is the date from my excel column and dob column in my table is of type **Date/Time** and Format as **Short Date**. My problem now is all my rows in dob column in  **Persons** table becomes: **30/12/1899**. How to fix this?

Comment: Try formatting it as `"yyyy-mm-dd"`

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/771902/1521579)

Comment: Use: `VALUES('" & xlWs.Cells(i, 8) & "',#" & Format(xlWs.Cells(i, 9), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);`.